# Merging two data frames in long format based on date

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have a 2 data frames, one (`df1`) that records the daily occurrence of different activities and another (`df2`) that records properties of the occurred activity during the day.

From `df1` it is possible to identify the repeated occurrence of an activity as well the duration. When the day starts is specified by the `Date` variable.

For example:

- `id` 12 the occurrence starts at day1 and ends at d7. In this case the occurrence is 7 and duration is 11.
- for `id` 123 the week starts at day 5 and ends at d7; occurred in repeated order because of there are gap days at day 6 and duration is 6 and id 123 (starts at day6 ends at day 7) occurred 2 times consecutively and duration 6.

In `df1` the variable Date defines the day when the record started. For example id 12 record started at day1 and so on.

I would like to identify if during the consecutive occurrence if there are records on the activity properties in `df2`.

For example id 12, occurred 7 times and duration is 12 there is record for Wednesday (day3 in `df1`) and this record corresponds to the 3 day of the consecutive occurrence. For id 123 there is no data (eg. no consecutive occurrence) but for id 10 for 6 day occurrence and duration 18 there is a record on the 6th day.

Df1:

```
id   day1 day2 day3 day4 day5 day6  day7   Date
 12    2    1    2    1    1    3    1     Mon
123    0    3    0    3    3    0    3     Fri
 10    0    3    3    3    3    3    3     Sat
```

Df2:

```
    id   c1 c2  Date
    12   3   3   Wednesday
   123   3   2   Fri
     10  3   1   Sat
```

Outcome:

```
 id c1 c2  Occurrence Position
 12 3   3     7          3
123 0   0     0          0
 10 3   1     2          1
```

Sample data: df1

```
structure(list(id = c(12L, 123L, 10L), day1 = c(2L, 0L, 3L), 
    day2 = c(1L, 3L, 3L), day3 = c(2L, 0L, 3L), day4 = c(1L, 
    3L, 3L), day5 = c(1L, 3L, 3L), day6 = c(3L, 0L, 3L), day7 = c(1L, 
    3L, 3L), Date = c("Monday", "Friday", "Saturday")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000002a81a571ef0>)
```

df2:

```
structure(list(id = c(12, 123, 10), c1 = c(3, 3, 3), c2 = c(3, 
2, 1), Date = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Friday", "Saturday", 
"Wednesday"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: what is the meaning of c1 and c2 in `df2`

Comment: and why c1 and c2 are 0 in outcome?

Comment: @ava describes different characteristics of the activities occurred in a successive order. Basically it suggest that there are observations at that point.

Comment: @ava for example in the case of id 12 there is a record made on Wednesday about the occuring activity. Furthermore as during the week in the case the activity occured 7 times this record was made during the 3 day.

Comment: @ c1 and c2 are in outcome because in am if there are suggestion about successive  occurrences and if any records were made and when they were made.

Comment: If 123 started on Wed and  a record was made on Sunday, how would outcome look like?

Comment: @ava so 123 id; the activity did not occurred in successive order there is a gap day; so i am not interested about its records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `dplyr` (maybe not the shortest one):

```r
# library
library(tidyverse)

# get data
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(12L, 123L, 10L), 
               day1 = c(2L, 0L, 3L), 
               day2 = c(1L, 3L, 3L), 
               day3 = c(2L, 0L, 3L), 
               day4 = c(1L,3L, 3L), 
               day5 = c(1L, 3L, 3L), 
               day6 = c(3L, 0L, 3L), 
               day7 = c(1L,3L, 3L), 
               Date = c("Monday", "Friday", "Saturday")),
               row.names = c(NA,-3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))


df2 <- structure(list(id = c(12, 123, 10),
                      c1 = c(3, 3, 3), 
                      c2 = c(3, 2, 1),
                      Date = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Friday", "Saturday","Wednesday"),
                                       class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")


# change days to numeric (will help you later)
df1 %>% mutate(
  Date_nr_df1=case_when(
    Date=="Monday" ~ 1,
    Date=="Tuesday" ~2,
    Date=="Wednesday" ~3,
    Date=="Thursday" ~4,
    Date=="Friday" ~5,
    Date=="Saturday" ~6,
    Date=="Sunday" ~7)) -> df1

df2 %>% mutate(
  Date_nr_df2=case_when(
    Date=="Monday" ~ 1,
    Date=="Tuesday" ~2,
    Date=="Wednesday" ~3,
    Date=="Thursday" ~4,
    Date=="Friday" ~5,
    Date=="Saturday" ~6,
    Date=="Sunday" ~7)) -> df2

# combine data by the id column
left_join(df1,df2, by=c("id")) -> df     

# adjust data   
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>% # to make changes per row
  mutate(days=paste0(day1,day2,day3,day4,day5,day6,day7)) %>% #pastes the values together
  mutate(days_correct=substring(days,Date_nr_df1)) %>% # applies the start day
  mutate(Occurrence_seq=str_split(days_correct, fixed("0"))[[1]][1]) %>% # extracts all days before 0
  mutate(Occurrence=nchar(Occurrence_seq)) %>%  ## counts these days
  mutate(Occurrence=case_when(Occurrence==1 ~ 0, TRUE ~ as.numeric(Occurrence))) %>% # sets Occurrence to 0 if there is no consecutive occurrence
  mutate(Position=Date_nr_df2-Date_nr_df1+1) %>% ## calculates the position you wanted
  mutate(c1=case_when(Occurrence==0 ~0, TRUE ~ c1),
         c2=case_when(Occurrence==0 ~0, TRUE ~c1),
         Position=case_when(Occurrence==0 ~ 0, TRUE ~ as.numeric(Position))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% ungroups the df
  select(id,c1,c2,Occurrence,Position) # selects the wanted variables
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>      id    c1    c2 Occurrence Position
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1    12     3     3          7        3
#> 2   123     0     0          0        0
#> 3    10     3     3          2        1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: many thanks for your time  when you have time could yopu please explain the code

Comment: many thanks for the code and explanation - if you have time could please look at this question. The difference are the time steps (95 x 7) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61187493/identify-consecutive-sequences-based-on-a-given-variable/61187921?noredirect=1#comment108250967_61187921